# How do I make a responsive header for an e-commerce website with sticky icons?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently designing a website for a friend, and I was wondering how do I make a responsive header/navigation bar for an e-commerce website with icons that remain sticky up top? The way I currently have it set up, every time it gets viewed on a mobile device, 3 cart icons all drop down to the bottom whenever I click on the sandwich icon.

I'm using the latest version of Bootstrap.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/kiwi.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
          Company Name
        </a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shop</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Instructions</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">The Science</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="ml-auto">
            <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/10154/shopping-cart-empty-side-view.svg" width="30" height="30" alt="">
            <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/10154/shopping-cart-empty-side-view.svg" width="30" height="30" alt="">
            <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/10154/shopping-cart-empty-side-view.svg" width="30" height="30" alt="">
        </div>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is getting the '.ml-auto' div just below your 'Company Name'-anchor (a) tag.

Otherwise you can achieve that using css or changing the markup.

edit:
You can use a CSS based solution:

```
.ml-auto {
  position: absolute;
  right: 60px;
  top: 10px;
}

button.navbar-toggler{  
  position: absolute;
  align-self: flex-end;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I did that. I moved the '.ml-auto' div tag just below the 'Company Name' tag.

However, whenever the screen is NOT at mobile width, the list are now to the right of the 3 icons. I wanted it so that the links remained between the logo and the 3 icons, and when the screen gets responsive, the list gets compiled into the button, but the 3 icons remain sticky at the upper right.